# Send an ajax request inside Jenkins build

Tags: curl, jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins and deploying the ruby applications. 
I have created a job and added shell script to send an ajax POST using curl command.

```
curl -k -X POST https://path/action --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

When i execute this job, i am getting the below error message,

```
curl: /JENKINS_PATH/sap_bobj/enterprise_xi40/linux_x64/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.12.9' not found (required by /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2)
```

Kindly help on this.

Comment: What is "trying to hit a URL"? An Ant script? XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is a web browser concept and it is unclear what XMLHttpRequest has to do with scripts called by Jenkins.

Comment: @ChadNouis - I have a job in my jenkins after which the successful execution of it, I am trying to build one more job to send a xhr post request to a url and trigger it. I have tried with HTTP Request plugin of Jenkins which didn't allow me to send xhr request. So i am trying with ant xml script or any script or plugin to do the job.